# Square wave into emitter follower

Tags: bjt, emitter-follower

I put a square wave of relatively low **rise** and **fall** time (of about **10ns**), and wanted to see the response from an emitter follower output.

[image]

I put together the circuit and here's what I see on scope.
[image]

[image]

I could not explain why the fall times differ so much, and the fall time of the wave at the output increases with the emitter register.

In spice the waveforms look entirely different. The spice model is quite simply showing the discharging of the \$C_{BE}\$ capacitor, with the downward spike across **R1** as the direction of current flows reverses while discharging.

[image]

**So what is actually going on**?

The \$C_{BE}\$ capacitor should have discharged the way shown in the spice, but it does not in reality.

PS: I have done the circuit in Veroboard.

PS: Here are some Ft values with different resisters.

```
R1      Rise time     Fall Time
220       ~10ns          ~20ns
1k        ~10ns          ~57ns
10k       ~10ns          ~522ns
```

Comment: How are you measuring the voltages.  It could be ringing in the cable, probe capacitance.  What happens if you change R1 to 100 ohms, 10k ohms?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold The fall time increases with increase of emitter resister. At R1 = 220E, Ft = 20ns, with R1 = 10k, Ft = 522ns.

Comment: Right, so when it turns off it has to discharge all the capacitance through the emitter resistor.  For the 10 k RC ~ 0.5uS or a C of ~50 pf (maybe half that.)  So probe or cable capacitance.

Comment: Is this a x1 scope probe? If so, a x10 probe should be closer to the simulation. Add a capacitor across R1 in the simulation. (Start with 50pF as suggested by George Herold)

Comment: @Brian it is a x10 probe. But I haven't tried it with x1 probe yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as expected.  On the rising edge, the transistor is actively providing current to charge up the inevitable parasitic capacitance across the emitter resistor.

On the falling edge, there are two effects that slow down the edge.  First, the transistor is just off.  It's not actively removing charge from the emitter node, as it was doing in the inverse on the rising edge.  The voltage on the parasitic capacitor only discharges thru the resistor exponentially.  Second, it takes a little bit of time for the charge carriers to be swept out of the base region of the transistor, so for a short time it is still conducting.  Actually this effect is minimized by the transistor not being saturated.  Unless you have a slow transistor, I'd say the dominating effect is the exponential nature of the voltage decay.

To put some numbers on this, let's see how things work out with 3 pF of parasitic capacitance across the resistor.  (1 kΩ)(3 pF)= 3 ns.  The actual parasitic capacitance can vary significantly by type of resistor and build technique, so we don't really know what it is.  Still, this shows at least that observing this effect on your time scale is plausible.

Comment: So it could be due to the scope probe?

Comment: @Arjo: Part of it is due to the capacitance of the scope probe.  You should, of course, be using the probe's highest setting when a few pF of capacitance matters.  However, there will always be some parasitic capacitance, whether added to by a scope probe or not.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've got about 20-25pF from the scope probe. Try a 10:1 setting.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that line (1) is the input and line (2) is the output of your follower.

What happens is that in the first case (rise), the transistor allows for a large current to flow through C-E and therefore you have a rapid rise. In the second case (fall), the current is limited by the resistor and you have a simple exponential decay (and the B-E coupling).

Comment: This is confirmed by your measurement: fall time is proportional to the resistor, rise time is constant.